# New installation of Tridion 2013 CMS Server gives error

Tags: 2013, cme

I installated new Content Manager Server.

> Package:　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 SDL Tridion 2013
>
> OS : 　　　　　　　　　　　　     　  　　　   Windows Server 2012(64-bit)
>
> Web and Application server: 　IIS 8
>
> dotNet Framework : 　　　　　　　dotNet Framework 4.5
>
> Java:　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 Java SE 7.0(64-bit)
>
> DB:　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 SQL Server 2012(64-bit)

But when I try to access CMS server, I'm getting 3 errors as below.
Maybe I think that IIS (webservice) is problem. But I don't know how to troubleshoot.
Please tell me how to troubleshoot.

1) The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

2) Loading list of locales failed.

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

3) Loading list of languages failed.

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Comment: I think there might be a firewall involved. Try switching it off for investigation

Comment: You should look for errors in the Event Viewer. Both the Tridion log and the Application log (also look for warnings from ASP.NET, as it logs server side errors as such)

Comment: >dear user978511. Thank you answer my quesion. I try swich firewall off, but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Something's off with that server, I'd probably try scanning through event viewer for errors (not directly related to Tridion, but IIS and .NET events), and possibly use something like ProcMon to check for weird errors or access restrictions.

Comment: >dear  Peter Kjaer.  Thank you answer my question. I look for errors in the Application log of the Event Viewer. I find the Application return error. So I try to solve Application error.

Comment: >dear Nuno Linhares.  Thank you answer my question. I look for errors in the Application log of the Event Viewer. I find the Application return error. So I try to solve Application error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you open the web.config in the below directory?

```
\%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\
```

and ensure that the below line:

`<add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="localhost:80"/>`

Matches that of the IIS binding information.  For example if you have a binding of server.corp.eu on port 80, then you'd need to change this to:

`<add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="server.corp.eu:80"/>`

Following this, restart the SDL Tridion Service Host.

Comment: Thank you answer my question. I open the web.congig in the \web\WebUI\WebRoot. And ensure the line. (<add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="localhost:81">)  Port for Tridion is 81.

Answer (score 1):

I find that web.config in the `\%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\`  is mistake.

the below line is mistake

```
<add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="localhost:81"/>
```

**before**

```
   <add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="localhost:81"/>
```

**after**

```
   <add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:81"/>
```

I change hostname(value attribute) to IP adress(value attribute).
Maybe name resolution doesn't work.